# LOOP through column to replace same value with different names SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

| id | dept |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | **b** |
| 1 | **b** |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | **b** |

And I'd like to rename values like this

| id | dept |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | **b1** |
| 1 | **b2** |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | **b1** |

All values in dept are grouped by id, same departments repeat each group.  I'm unsure how to make a loop that does one pass per id (replace 'b' with 'b1'), then a second pass (replace 'b' with 'b2').

Or does once per table, but each statement ends after one replace per id.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the primary key of your table? To perform such update, we would need a PK.

Comment: Primary key is 'id'

Comment: Yes, but `id` is not unique, so it can't be a PK. That's the problem here.

Comment: Clarification: each row needs a unique id?  

If I were to insert a running sum column as pk, what would the solution look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to loop. We can just use `row_number()`.

```
select  id
       ,case when dept = 'b' then dept||row_number() over(partition by id, dept) else dept end as dept
from    t
```

| id | dept |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b1 |
| 1 | b2 |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | b1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LMMuaPxb)